# ESP32 CAM can't upload to firebase

Tags: database, firebase, file-upload, esp32, eeprom

Hi I want to upload a face sample from the esp32 cam to firebase but I can't find the line of code that shows the process of saving to the esp32cam flash memory. the code I use is the default code from esp32cam. can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is pretty broad and we're not quite sure what your asking. Are you asking about how to upload data to Firebase? Or are you asking about some off-site section of code... or about your code or something else?? Please update and clarify the question.

Comment: I wanted to ask how to upload images from esp32 cam to firebase storage, but because it failed then I changed the storage using SD Card. But I got an error like the following
Card Mount Failed

Comment: Understood. SO is not a code writing service and can really only help with existing code you've attempted. Write some code and when you get stuck, post the code and your troubleshooting and we'll take a look. Since you are new here, please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)